# Using additional C++ libraries in Xcode

Tags: xcode

There is a possibility in MS Visual Studio to go to Tools->Options->Projects and solutions->VC++ Directories and to add header and binary files of additional C++ libraries, and compiler uses them for every project if they are needed. How to achieve such result in Xcode 3.2?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in the "Link Binary With Libraries" build phase under your target.  Right click on it, and select "Existing Files..." -- then select the library you wish to link to.  You don't have to use a framework as implied earlier.

Answer (score 1):

XCode uses the concept of a "Framework" for such a purpose. Basically, a "Framework" is header files and libraries in a bundle. You can find more information on frameworks [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WhatAreFrameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002303).

Add a framework to you project by right clicking your project in XCode and choose "Add framework". Make sure it is also referenced in your build target. The resource above has all necessary  information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an option to do this automatically for all projects. You have to manually set the include paths, library paths and link flags for each target.

One thing that may work though is to set the standard GCC variables, eg CFLAGS, CXXFLAGS, LDFLAGS which you can set up in `/etc/profile` or `~/.bash_profile`